# How to deal with weird HTML characters? HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html

So I was looking at this..

```
<a href="/v-renovation-contracting-handyman/mississauga-peel-region/basement-bathroom-kitchen-renovation/1358026706?enableSearchNavigationFlag=true" class="title enable-search-navigation-flag">
   BASEMENT ★ BATHROOM ★ KITCHEN RENOVATION ★</a>
```

How do I deal with weird characters like that star ( `★` ) up there?

Because this is what it prints out.

```
BASEMENT â˜… BATHROOM â˜… KITCHEN RENOVATION â˜…
```

Do you encode it in a special way or what do you do?

This is what I use to print out that text

```
var ListingTitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Listing.InnerText.Trim());

//Traverse through the DOM
            var Nodes = DOM.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class = 'description']/a");

            var listTest = new List<DataContext>();


            foreach (var Listing in Nodes)
            {
                //Get the href
                var ListingTitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Listing.InnerText.Trim());
                Console.WriteLine(ListingTitle);
                if (ListingTitle.Contains(','))
                {
                    string newTitle = ListingTitle.Replace(',', '.');
                    Title = newTitle;
                }
                else
                {
                    Title = ListingTitle;
                }
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Updated the question with some more code

Comment: The `â˜…` is what the string output gives me

Comment: I see exactly what I posted above `BASEMENT â˜… BATHROOM â˜… KITCHEN RENOVATION â˜…`

Comment: I ran it again and now it's not showing that weird symbol, but if I write it out to a textfile it prints that out.

Comment: It shows `?` instead of `â˜…` int he console, but the textfile contains `â˜…`

Comment: That's where the issue was! I totally forgot at StreamWriter had a Encoding as it's 3rd parameter! I set it to ASCII and now it prints out the `?` which is much better than `â˜…` I am going to play around with it and see if I can get it to print out the star which I think is highly unlikely but I will try try try!

Comment: Alright, I opened fiddler and it seems as if the html content was encoded using UTF8 so I used taht and voila!

Comment: The html encoding and the text encoding are not related. If it works then that is because of how you look at the text file.

Answer (score -1):

The issue I was facing had to do with the encoding.
The website content was encoded using the UTF8 encoding table

and by default when printing the text out with StreamWriter, it does not use UTF8.
What is uses exactly I could not find but I had to set the Encoding parameter to `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: The html encoding and the text encoding are not related. They do not have to match.

Comment: Using CsvHelper.